# White Line at bottom of UITableView Cell at end of section in Grouped TableView (iOS 5)

Tags: iphone, user-interface, uitableview, ios5, visual-glitch

I have noticed a change in the look of the tableview cells in iOS 5, and I googles around a bit to see if anyone else had noticed. [This fellow](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111012145715AATDiK7) did, and posted [this image](http://i51.tinypic.com/24ybvjd.png). I can't reproduce it on every uitableview (if I could I would know where it came from and I could get rid of it), but it is certainly causing me a problem on one of my tableviews. Has anyone else noticed this - better yet, has anyone else found a way to get rid of it?

Comment: I think it's intentional - notice how it makes the table look slightly recessed?

Comment: Yeah.. but when you are doing custom tableview cells sometimes it doesn't make your cells look nicer, but worse. That's the problem I'm having. I just wonder if there is a way to get rid of it.

Comment: Does anyone know how to get rid of this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had this issue, on an iOS4 phone or simulator it looks fine but for iOS5 it was a problem. I discovered that the issue was with the separator style for the table view. It looks like the default value is set to etched for iOS5. I have gone through my code and added the following line to my init method for all grouped table view controllers:

```
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
```

Which has fixed the issue for me, although I also set the following as the color appeared to be white not grey as in the previous version:

```
    self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
```

It was a problem for me as I have changed the background on all of my table views and the extra line didn't look good for my app.

Answer (score 2):

use:

self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;